# SQL: Combine Records with Same ReferenceID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following records inside my table

```
ID   StudentID   Semester   Grade     
1    1           First      100
2    1           Second     90
3    2           First      90
4    1           Third      85
```

I want to combine all the records of Student ID 1 in one record

```
StudentID   First   Second   Third
1           100     90       85 
2           90      null     null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whch DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't mention what RDBMS you are using, try this one out.

```
SELECT  StudentID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Semester = 'First' THEN Grade ELSE NULL END) AS First,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Semester = 'Second' THEN Grade ELSE NULL END) AS Second,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Semester = 'Third' THEN Grade ELSE NULL END) AS Third
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY StudentID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32a6f/1)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal leave you answer as it is, it is a very good answer. trust me. don't delete it. i'm voting it to undelete. `:D`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: I voted to undelete as well. I just wanted to know what the reason for posting a SQL Server specific solution was, that's all